# Boolean Indexing in Pandas Dataframes with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop specific rows from my 3-column dataframe based on values in two of the columns. I have been trying to use Boolean indexing, but have not been seeing the results I expect.

Example: I want to remove the single row with 'SchoolID' equal to 1234, and the 'State' column equal to New York. These are unique to this row in the dataframe.

I tried the following but more rows were deleted than I expected:

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] != 1234) & (DF['State'] != 'New York')]
```

When I tried the following, the inverse, the single row I wanted was produced:

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] == 1234) & (DF['State'] == 'New York')]
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy? Is there something I am missing about Boolean indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] != 1234) & (DF['State'] != 'New York')]
```

is not the inverse of

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] == 1234) & (DF['State'] == 'New York')]
```

when inverting a condition, you have to change the = operator (which you did), but also the & operator : & becomes | and vice-versa.

Finally, the condition you want is :

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] != 1234) | (DF['State'] != 'New York')]
```

ie for a given row

- if SchoolID != 1234 => keep
- if State != New-York => keep
- if SchoolID = 1234 : go to next condition

  - if State = New York => keep
  - if State != New York => keep

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). If you want the inverse of

```
a and b
```

then you want

```
(not a) or (not b)
```

So for your case, just grab

```
DF[(DF['SchoolID'] != 1234) | (DF['State'] != 'New York')]
```